scipy's solve_ivp having trouble solving simple ivp
I'm attempting to solve a very simple IVP in Python in order to do error analysis:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def dh_dt_zerodriver(t, h):
    return -2 / h

t = 50
steps = 10
dt = t / steps
t_span = [0, t]
t_eval = np.arange(0, t + dt, dt)

h0 = 5

sol = solve_ivp(dh_dt_zerodriver, t_span=t_span, y0=[h0], t_eval=t_eval)

However, the solution will not compute as it runs for an indefinite amount of time. I have used solve_ivp to solve more complex IVPs without analytical solutions, but this one seems to have me stumped despite it seemingly being a fairly simply problem.
My paper is based on using the RK45 method, but if I must use some different numerical method then it is okay.

This looks like it has really weird behavior around h = 0. If it's at h = 0.00001, then it should move in the -h direction very quickly, until it reaches h = -0.00001, where it moves in the +h direction very quickly. If you subdivide this partway through, you'll get a different result, e.g if you split this range into [0.00001, 0.000005, -0.00001], you'll get a very different value. Is this behavior when crossing 0 intended?

Modify to avoid dividing by zero. To start, observe -2/h=-2*h/h^2. To avoid a zero divisor, modify to -2*h/(eps+h*h). The modified equation has the zero axis as asymptote. The smaller eps, the smaller the step size in explicit methods. With implicit methods, the step size should be relatively large, more depending on the error tolerances than on eps.

The problem is the domain you want your solution. Your ODE is h'(t) = -2/h(t) where h(0) = 5. The analytical solution is h(t) = sqrt(25 - 4t). For t < 6.25, the solution is real, but for t >= 6.25, the solution becomes complex. If you were to instead integrate over t = [0, 6], you would quickly get the correct result.

Hi, if I want a complex solution I then pass h0 as complex(2). The solution does indeed generate an imaginary component, but it is always 0. How can I make it so that it properly generates the imaginary component?
